# Return(value); not working in function

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I call This function:

```
function getweb(addr){
    request(addr, function (err, response, body) {
    let artlatestjson = JSON.parse(body);
    aart = artlatestjson.title;
    alink = artlatestjson.url;
    ascore = "｜  Score " + artlatestjson.score;
    return(aart)
  });
}
```

With:

```
console.log(getweb(jsonfileaddres))
```

(jsonfileaddres being url of the json file)

It allways returns undefined, even though aart is set to the corect thing.

Comment: Your return statement is actually returning from the `request` callback, not from `getweb`

Comment: `return request(...);` if that is implemented.